# How to use card-deck with dynamically generated data?

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to display data use card-deck. So every three data from database, it will make a new line. So, one line just have 3 datas, how to fix it?

Here my code, it display one line with all data from database and how to fix it?

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    if($i % 3 == 0){?>
<div class="card-deck ml-2 mr-2 mb-3">
  <?php $no=1; foreach ($data as $d ){?>
  <div class="card border-dark">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/koceng.jpeg')?>" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text"><?php echo $no++ ?>
          <?php echo $d->nim ?>
          <?php echo $d->nama ?>
          <?php echo $d->kelas ?>
          <?php echo $d->nama_jurusan ?>
          <?php echo $d->fakultas ?></p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
    <?php }}?>
```

Thankyou.

Comment: How do you define new line? Do you have a wrapper element that you can put only  elements into? Also, that nested `foreach` makes no sense. You're trying to iterate the same data as the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Please add some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_cards.asp).

```
<?php $i = 0;foreach ($data as $d ){?> <!-- i is for count number of cards -->
<?php if($i%3 == 0){ ?> <!-- printing card-deck per 3 cards -->
<div class="card-deck ml-2 mr-2 mb-3">
<?php } ?>
  <div class="card border-dark">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/koceng.jpeg')?>" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text"><?php echo $no++ ?> <!-- i don't know why $no is used for -->
          <?php echo $d->nim ?>
          <?php echo $d->nama ?>
          <?php echo $d->kelas ?>
          <?php echo $d->nama_jurusan ?>
          <?php echo $d->fakultas; $i++;?></p> <!-- increment i by one per card -->
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php if($i%3 == 0){ ?>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```